# Django simple search with Class based views and forms.py

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have been trying to do a variation of what Williams Vincent did on this page: https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-search-tutorial .
I am using Django 3.2 so if there are modifications, I need to make I have not identified them. I am having some troubles.
This what I made which worked just fine.

my_search.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
    {% for city in object_list %}
      <li>
        {{city.name}} &emsp; {{city.city_no}}  
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import City

class SearchResutlsView(ListView): # test version 
    model = City
    template_name = "search_results.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return City.objects.filter(name__icontains='Boston')
```

Now it is time to add forms.py, but when I made the below changes to the code it does not work. What am I missing? There are no errors displayed. I get a blank html.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
  <form class="d-flex" method='get' action="{% url 'city:search_results' %}">
    {{ form }}
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" value="qu">Search Name</button>
  </form>    
   {% for city in city_list %}
    <li>
        {{city.name}} &emsp; {{city.city_no}}  
    </li>
   {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    q = forms.CharField(label='Search label', max_length=50, strip=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import FormView, ListView
from .models import City

class SearchResutlsView(FormView):
   model = City
   form_class = SearchForm
   template_name = "city/search_results.html"

   def get_queryset(self):
       query = self.request.Get.get("q")
       if query:
           city_list = City.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
       else:
           city_list = City.objects.none()
       return  city_list
```

Answer (score 1):

First, Your method should be POST not get.

Second, you need to add CSRF token.

something like that:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
  <form class="d-flex" method='post' action="{% url 'city:search_results' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" value="qu">Search Name</button>
  </form>    
   {% for city in city_list %}
    <li>
        {{city.name}} &emsp; {{city.city_no}}  
    </li>
   {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

and in views.py

```
query = self.request.POST.get("q")
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work either. I changed HTML `method='post'` added `{% csrf_token %}`. In views.py `.POST.` and added `success_url = city/search_results/`.